# Two definitions of a monovalued morphism

Tags: category-theory, order-theory, lattice-orders, dagger-categories

Let fix some [dagger category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagger_category) every of Hom-sets of which is a complete lattice, and the dagger functor agrees with the lattice order.

I define a morphism $f$ to be *monovalued* when $f\circ f^{-1}\le \operatorname{id}_{\operatorname{Dst} f}$.

Is the following concept somehow related with the concept of monovaluedness?

I call a morphism $f$ *metamonovalued* when $(\bigwedge G) \circ f = \bigwedge_{g \in G} ( g \circ f)$ for every set $G$ of morphims (provided that the sources and domains of the morphisms are suitable). Here $\bigwedge$ denoted the infimum on the above mentioned complete lattice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think about $\mathcal Rel$, the category of sets and relations as prototype, you can construct counterexamples for the 'monavalued$\implies$metamonovalued' implication.

Nevertheless, this implication holds generally with an additional condition, namely if $f$ is monovalued *and is 'everywhere defined'* ($f^\dagger \circ f\ge 1_{{\rm Src}\, f}$), then it is also metamonovalued, as proved below:

Because of order preserving of composition (I guess, it is also assumed!), we always have
$$\left(\bigwedge G\right)\circ f\le \bigwedge_{g\in G}(g\circ f)\,.$$
For the other direction, $\big(\bigwedge_{g\in G}(g\circ f)\big)\circ f^{\dagger}\le \bigwedge_{g\in G}(g\circ f\circ f^\dagger)\le \bigwedge G$. By the additional condition we have
$$\bigwedge_{g\in G}(g\circ f) \le
\big(\bigwedge_{g\in G}(g\circ f)\big)\circ f^{\dagger}\circ f\le \left(\bigwedge G\right)\circ f \,. $$

I suppose that the other implication can be easily '*done wrong*' by adding new fictive morphisms or removing existing ones.

Comment: No, contrary to what you say, in the category $\mathcal Rel$ every monovalued morphism is metamonovalued: See proposition 3.83 in my book: http://www.mathematics21.org/algebraic-general-topology.html (if I mistake, correct me)

Comment: What about the reverse implication: metamonovalued $\Rightarrow$ monovalued?